# Aliasing with primitives variables

Tags: java

I have `Point class` (not the build in class) and one of my constructors:

```
public class Point
{
    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    public Point(Point p)
    {
        _x = p._x;
        _y = p._y;
    }
}
```

In this case is it OK the copy the new point members in my constructor or i need to do something else to avoid aliasing?
What about copying a string?

Comment: what do you mean with copy string?

Comment: The same way i copy the point x and y, if i have string to copy - do i need to do string st = new string(MyString) ?

Comment: Just try build constuctor with string parameter and check by yourself!

Comment: @user2214609 strings are immutable, so you don't need to create new string object, just use already existing one since its value (characters inside) can't be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. Primitive assignments are by direct value. When you assign an object reference, however, you're just assigning the reference, so you'll need to copy that object that's a field.

For copying `int`s, `double`s, and other primitives, this is fine. In addition, this also works for String objects (but is not guaranteed for any other objects) as strings are *immutable*.

Comment: String is also Primitive ? can you elaborate about direct value ?

Comment: @user2214609 String is not primitive, `String a = b;` creates aliasing. But since strings are immutable, this aliasing cannot wreak havoc.

Comment: @hexafraction That behavior has nothing to do with value types vs. reference types: `MyMutableType a = new MyMutableType(2); MyMutableType b = a; a = new MyMutableType(3); System.out.println(b);` also prints 2, not 3 (with proper boilerplate constructor and `toString`). See http://ideone.com/pUTcKC

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to copy them because these are value types and will be copied by value.
As for string, you can copy it too, but this time because strings in Java are immutable.
Cheers.